# How to route to a page in a post request that is itself called through an XHR request?

Tags: javascript, routes, reactjs, xmlhttprequest

If a user clicks a button, then an xhr request is made to go to the POST:

```
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();   // new HttpRequest instance 
        xhr.open("POST", "/registration");
        xhr.addEventListener("load", e => {
            console.log(xhr.responseText)
        });

        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify(this.state));
```

Here is the POST request.

```
router.post('/registration', function *(req, res, next) {
console.info("trying to get the user");
//console.log(this.request.body);

let {name, password} = this.request.body

let taken = yield utils.nameTaken(name)

if(taken){
    //redirect to reg page
    console.log("taken!");
    //this.response.redirect("/registration");
    //res.redirect('/');
    console.log(req);

}
else{
    userSchema.createUser(name, password, function(err, user){
    //console.log(err, user);
    });
    //this.response.redirect("/success");
    //redirect to success page
}

})
```

What I'm trying to do is when taken is true, then the client gets redirected to the route '/' and when taken is false, then the client gets redirected to '/success'. I'm having trouble doing these redirects, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in this fashion, at least not if I'm understanding you correctly. What currently happens it that the browser receives the response (/success or /) as the answer to its XMLHTTP-request. The redirect, however, has already happened at this point. xhr.request.body will contain whatever GET /success and GET / return.

What you probably want to do is simply return a status code (I believe good REST practice would be 403 for a failure, 200 for success) and react to that on the client.